# Email issue with kik developer botsworth

Tags: kik

I am trying to  make a bot on kik, but when the developer bot "botsworth" comes up he always says i need to verify my email, even though my email is verified. I enter my email, and then i get a "Oops, something went wrong, Please enter your email address again" message. I have tried using multiple emails, has anyone ran into the same problem or have any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Although Kik's documentation doesn't make it obvious, and (as you discovered) you can get most of the way through the verification process, **creation of new bots is no longer allowed** and most of the existing bots have been disabled.