# Kik bot show "Pending Approval" always

Tags: node.js, bots, kik

I am creating a Kik bot. It doesn’t seem to be technically difficult.
I have created a new Kikbot  under a Kik account A .
User A can automatically subscribe to Kikbot,
but when another account B subscribes to Kikbot,
it shows that the number of subscribers exceeds limit.
I find  some informations, and it seems that Kikbot need join to Bot Shop .
About half a month ago, I submitted Kikbot information to dev.kik.com,
but the reply always is Pending Approval from then on.
I am very confused now.
Is there any way, what is going on?
and what is the problem?
Let  Kikbot be displayed on the Bot Shop as soon as possible?
I  even sent  three emails to Bots@kik.com ,
but No response.
Do I need   tell my boss that I am going to quit this project now ?

Answer (score 0):

Same for me, very fast to deny if bot does not answer to text for example, but none if the bot is ok...

Ups, check that comment:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61868376/15436636